# Angular 8 paths

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a project with Angular 8 i try use in my

```
src/app/helpers/auth.guard.ts
 import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/services';
```

My AuthenticationService ts file have a path in

```
src/app/services/authentication.service.ts
```

when i run ng serve i get the error

```
ERROR in src/app/helpers/auth.guard.ts(4,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@app/services'.
```

**this is my tsconfig.js**

```
 {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
        "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**This my tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I try to run the project with --aot and this doesn't work

Comment: Are you exporting `AuthenticationService` in `src/app/services/` ?

Comment: yeah i declare export class AuthenticationService

Comment: Does the error go away if you change import statement to `import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service.ts';` ?

Comment: @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {} in src/app/services/authentication.service.ts

Comment: work this import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service'; but i need to work with @app/services or @app/services/authentication.service

Comment: Answered. Try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what could be going wrong:

Your Authentication service resides at following path:

```
src/app/services/authentication.service.ts
```

But when you try to import it using: `import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/services'`, it tries to import the service from `services` directory. Your `service` directory doesn't export authentication service, therefore you get this error.

Here's how you can fix it:

1. Create a file called `index.ts` in `services` directory so it's located at path: `src/app/services/index.ts`.
2. In this `index.ts` file, add following export statement:

```
export * from './authentication.service.ts';
```

This will export your service from `services` folder so your import statement will be able to locate Authentication service at `src/app/services/`.

As you already have an path alias in your tsconfig `"@app/*": ["src/app/*"]`, your import statement should resolve correctly.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Please consider upvoting as well. Thanks.